# Industrial applications

Tags: hardware, performance

I've been wondering what's the durability of the RPI and the maximum temperature it can operate on. Is it possible to use it to replace some industrial computers?

I'm thinking set-top boxes for hotel TVs or turnstyle controls.

As anybody tested it in a "real world" scenario?

Answer (score 4):

There is a question about the temperature limits for RaspberryPi in the [official FAQ](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs). It may be possible to replace some industrial computers with RPI but keep in mind that it was not its design purpose. It was designed as cheap educational computer, not industrial equipment. A lot of today's electronic equipment is used in ways totally different than the ones they where designed for, so it is nothing unusual. However, there is just no warranty it will work as expected.

Comment: I'm aware the RPI was designed as an educational computer. I was just wondering if anybody has tried to use it in industrial applications and how did the RPI fared.

Comment: Look up rasberry pi supercomputer on youtube... again though this was used for educational system at a college... but still I dont think they would invest 4k if they wouldn't last...  But again there is still no warranty

Answer (score -1):

I have use it as barcode scanner and as industrial camera. If power supppy is designed properly and you do as little as possible writing on SD card it should be ok. Scanner works now for cca 1 year.

Comment: It more than two years of anecdotal evidence now. Of real world scenario in industry. But just out of curiosity what evidence do you need?